# Windows cant see second mointor

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

So this problem is really strange because it only started happening today when my screen randomly lost signal (power still on). Now no matter what windows can only recognise one monitor, so I can plug them each in individually and they will both be recognised however when both are plugged in only one is.

I've updated windows, i've even tried downgrading my graphics card drivers but to no avail. I just have no idea what the problem could be.

Answer (score 1):

You should press `WinKey + P` and choose `Extend` because by default it is `Computer` only.

Comment: Doing so does absolutely nothing

Comment: HELP help me help me

Comment: Right click on Desktop -> choose `Screen Resolution` -> Is your second monitor is grey out? or it is active?

Comment: no, there's nothing there except for my main monitor

Comment: Click `Detect`, is there any monitor now?

Comment: noooooooooooope